# Makefile with cpp and header files

Tags: c++, makefile

Currently I have a program that has a `main.cpp`, `linked_queue.cpp` and a `linked_queue.h`, and I am trying to write a simple Makefile, but I am running into a linker issue.

In `main.cpp` I have included the header file, `#include"linked_queue.h"`, but I am getting a linker error. The following is there error on my machine:

```
clang++ -g3 -std=c++1z -Wconversion -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic -c linked_queue.cpp
clang++ -g3 -std=c++1z -Wconversion -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic -c main.cpp
clang++ -g3 -std=c++1z -Wconversion -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic  linked_queue.o main.o -o main
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "LinkedQueue<int>::push(int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "LinkedQueue<int>::~LinkedQueue()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is the current contents of my Makefile:

```
main:  linked_queue.o main.o
    clang++ -g3 -std=c++1z -Wconversion -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic  linked_queue.o main.o -o main

linked_queue.o: linked_queue.cpp linked_queue.h
    clang++ -g3 -std=c++1z -Wconversion -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic -c linked_queue.cpp

main.o: main.cpp linked_queue.h
    clang++ -g3 -std=c++1z -Wconversion -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic -c main.cpp


clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.dSYM main
```

I thought I included all the dependencies. Any thoughts on what I have missed?

Comment: In `clang++ -g3 -std=c++1z -Wconversion -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic  linked_queue.o main.o -o main`, try changing the order of the two .o files.

Comment: `clang++ -g3 -std=c++1z -Wconversion -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic main.o linked_queue.o -o main` made the change but still the error.  I initially thought that would be the issue.

Comment: Have you defined the `push(int)` method inside `LinkedQueue` class?

Comment: @Aamir, yes I have

Comment: Is `LinkedQueue` a template that has [been implemented in a cpp file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)?

Comment: That is exactly what is happening! I thought you could just implement templates in a `.cpp`. Appreciate this!